# Woocommerce producuts shortcode display only two products per page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am building WooCommerce store with storefront child theme. In my shop page (`archive-product.php`) I'm using following code to display products:

```
<?php
        $filterArray = explode("/", "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);


        if(count($filterArray)>5) {
            echo do_shortcode('[products category="' . $filterArray[count($filterArray)-2] . '" per_page="30" limit="30" columns="3" paginate="true"]');
        }
        else {
            echo do_shortcode('[products per_page="30" limit="30" columns="3" paginate=true]');
        }
?>
```

When I don't pass `category` attribute to the shortcode, everything works as expected. But when I add `category`, my page display not 30, but only 2 products per page. Changing `products` to `product category` does not work at all. What could be the reason of such strange behaviour?

EDIT: I have some mess in my code, found following function in `functions.php`:

```
function modify_product_cat_query( $query ) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_tax("product_cat")){
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 2);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_product_cat_query' );
```

I thought that I finally found the issue, but even when I delete that sinppet or change value from 2 to 30, category page still displays only two products...

Comment: Can you confirm how many products assign to that category because when i test your code it's working correctly for me.

Comment: @GautamGolakiya yes, I have more that 60 products and they are divided into more than 30 pages with two products each.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `woocommerce_product_query` to change `posts_per_page`. check the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'change_posts_per_page', 999 );
function change_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 30);
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still shows me only two products per page (I changed post_per_page value in else statement of course). Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. You are on archive page so it is more easy to get current term. You don't have to fetch it from url.

```
    $term = get_queried_object();

    if( !empty( $term ) && !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[products category="' . $term->slug . '" per_page="6" limit="30" columns="3" paginate="true"]');
    } else {
        echo do_shortcode('[products per_page="30" limit="30" columns="3" paginate=true]');
    }
```

The issue you are facing product are not displaying more than 2 it's probably because there is something overriding posts_per_page.

Comment: Yes, ovveriding was the issue, but I still can't resolve it. Please check my edit.

Comment: Can you check "Blog pages show at most" from the settings->reading in backend.

Comment: I have value '10' there